# Relational algebra: selecting range (between numbers)

Tags: database, relational-database, algebra, relational-algebra

I can't seem to find it on the internet, which I find weird. My question: how do I show a `range` in `relational algebra`?

I am being asked this:

> Find user numbers of users who had points
>   in the range of 500-1700.

I checked this:
http://www.marcoullis.com/KNOWLEDGE/DATABASES/marcoullisp_knowledge_databases_relational_algebra.html

And came up with:

```
π user_numbers(σ points >= ‘500’ ^ points <= ’1700’ (USER ⋈ POINT TABLE))
```

Is this correct? If not, how should I do this?

*PS: ^ symbol stands for AND.*

Comment: What version of relational algebra were you told to use? (Ie either give a description or reference to the operators & what a "relation" is.) Ie are you *allowed* to put an AND in the expression in a RESTRICT?

Comment: Yes, I am allowed to put an AND, although nothing is given. I have no description, so I am assuming everything is permitted.

Comment: That web page is a poor reference. Find a college/university textbook/course (there are many online). PS How can we address your example if you don't tell us what base tables you have and what row they hold, ie under what circumstances a row goes into one? (Of course we can *guess*. And then you can *hope*.)

Comment: It's not about the words, it's about me doing the AND correctly and the RANGE correctly. Is this the way to define a range or not?

Comment: "It's not about the words" is not clear. Just like the writing in your question. Why do you expect an answer to an unclear question? (Eg you have told us nothing about USER & POINT.) You do seem to have the right idea in mind. (So now you can hope we guessed right.) PS Your expression doesn't even parse, and it seems unlikely that "TABLE" should be in it.

Comment: Does this mean that POINT TABLE is not being seen as 1 table, but two separate tables as there is no underscore but a space separating them?

Comment: What I mean is (NATURAL) JOIN takes a relation expression on each side, but two table names with a space between them is not usually a relation expression (table name), and usually we write things like "`σ` condition expression `(` relation expression `)`" but your parentheses don't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are allowed to use AND in the condition expression of a RESTRICT and your tables are how we can guess from your question then an expression something like what you wrote is correct.

You could also write something like

```
    π number (σ points >= 500 (USER ⋈ POINT))
⋈  π number (σ points <= 1700 (USER ⋈ POINT))
```

Or you could use INTERSECT instead of (NATURAL) JOIN there.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Confirmation. Thank you.